# How to set the default value in the view of an existing form, depending on the decision (boolean) field?

Tags: python, view, boolean, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change the view of the "Contacts/new" form when the "citizen" (I added it in my .py file as a boolean field) is ticked. When it is True, I want the "zip" field to be read-only type with default value "12345" , and when it is False just normally.

If I was not completely clear, or if you need my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a default value to the zip field, write an `onchange` method for field `citizen`.

Try something like this:

```
 @api.onchange('citizen')
 def onchange_citizen(self):
    if self.citizen:
       self.zip = 123456
```

And in the `view` set readonly true on the field `zip` when the value of citizen field is `True`

```
 <field name="zip" attrs="{'readonly':[('citizen','=',True)]}"/>
```

Hope  this  will help you.